# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED via spark-submit vs successful manual execution of python code

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

**python 2.7, aws emr 5.29** cluster bootstrapped with boto 3 on all it's nodes.

**Success** : ssh & execute a python program that inserts into dynamodb (tested on both master & a core node).  executed manually via `python test.py`

**Failure** :  spark-submit --jars   test.py (on master)
**Error** : From the stacktrace it is pointing to CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED to the dynamodb aws url.

Question:  what is spark-submit doing under the covers that requires authentication that straight python test.py did not require authentication?

Answer (score 0):

After adding ca bundle to aws config as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/set.html)  and re-ran via `spark-submit` `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` went away.